# How to convert npm start to ng serve in angular 2 applicaition?

Tags: angular

I'm using `npm start` to run my application.

Command `ng serve` isn't working.

How can I use `ng serve` and `ng build` for this application?

Comment: you are using npm start to run the node server or angular app currently?

Answer (score 1):

use below command for angular CLI.

npm install -g @angular/cli and try or for more help [click here](https://cli.angular.io/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Macbook, I'd recommend:

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

After you've installed this, get to your directory and now put

```
ng serve
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly need to install

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

if already installed follow next steps
Basically npm start is a script written inside package.json File in root directory

package.json

```
 "scripts": {
   "ng": "ng",
   "start": "ng serve --watch --progress --live-reload",
 }
```

So in order to run `npm start` command you should be in your root directory where **package.json** file exists